# how to limit the size of a JTable and its internal table model

Tags: java, swing, size, jtable, limit

I have a JTable using DefaultTableModel as its internal data model. It will receive packet from network and show the packet in the JTable. Now i want to limit data model size so that it will only contain the newest packets and drop of the oldest, but the DefaultTableModel uses a dataVector of type Vector which has no size limit. 
Could anybody please give some help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you always insert new rows at the top of the table, you could easily perform a check on the `TableModel` when you do so, and remove manually:

```
 model.insertRow(0,rowData);
 while (model.getRowCount() > myMaxRowCount) {
    model.removeRow(model.getRowCount()-1);
 }
```

Another option would be to put this process into an extension of `DefaultTableModel` (or even `AbstractTableModel`, which would allow you to ditch the `Vector` for something a bit more modern).  The Model could hold the maxRowCount that you want to maintain and then you can implement a new `updateModel` method that will do the `add` of the new data and the `remove` of the old.